# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Resulta y pasa que tengo dos tablas:

**Etiqueta y Prioridad**

los campos de la tabla **etiqueta**:

```
id
priority_tag_id
name
image
```

los campos de la tabla **prioridad**:

```
id
name
```

y así están mis tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y luego ejecuto la siguiente consulta:

```
INSERT INTO etiqueta (name, image, priority_tag_id) VALUES ("Spanish", "imagen_tag_spanish",1);
```

me da este error:

```
 #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UNIQ_389B783424F0A6A'
```

el número `1` que le paso a la consulta es un id de la tabla `Prioridad`, el cual es una fila existente.

Pasa así: Cuando tengo la tabla `Etiqueta` está totalmente vacía y ejecuto la consulta, me la ejecuta satisfactoriamente, pero cuando la vuelvo a ejecutar la misma consulta por segunda vez me da ese error.

Otra cosa que me di cuenta es que en la columna `priority_tag_id` de la tabla etiqueta no puedo insertar número repetidos (creo que es porque es foránea, pero aún así no entiendo), imagen:

Digamos, no puedo hacer una consulta como está:

```
INSERT INTO etiqueta (name, image, priority_tag_id) VALUES ("Spanish", "imagen_tag_spanish",1);
```

Ya que me daria error, porque el id 1 (foranea) ya existe en esa columna de la tabla `Etiqueta`.

La pregunta que yo hago, porque ese error, si simplemente es un id de la tabla `Prioridad` y este obviamente existe, la verdad no entiendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifica que la columna de llame foranea no tenga una restricción unique

Comment: Gracias, sucedía que tenia una relación uno a uno, y por eso no permitía valores repetidos, gracias!